# Bash script with if condition with and operator

Tags: bash, shell

I've created bash script with if-else condition and 'and' operator

```
if [ ps aux | grep -v 'grep --color=auto' ] && [ ps aux | grep '/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dproc_balanicer' ] ; then

   echo "HDFS BALANCER IS ALREADY RUNNING with PID"
   ps aux | grep '/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dproc_balancer' | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'

else

   echo "kinit to HDFS"
   kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hdfs.headless.keytab hdfs-kubpom@TAP.TRUE.TH
   hdfs dfsadmin -setBalancerbandwidth $1
   nodhup hdfs balancer > /tmp/hdfs-balancer-out_$(NOW).log 2> /tmp/hdfs-balancer-debug_$(NOW).log &

fi
```

but it always returns

```
line 5: [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

I don't know what's wrong in my bash 
what I've tried so far are

```
- if [[ -a ]]
- if { [ ] }
- if [ ] && [ ]
```

Comment: You don't put commands inside square backets.

Comment: @Barmar just updated the post, please check

Comment: I already answered.

Comment: This is [Bash Pitfalls #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D)

Comment: @BanthitaLimwilai : In addition to the correct answer and remarks posted here: If you *do* want to use `[ ... ]` in a correct way, see `man test`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're testing the result of a command with `if`, you don't put it inside the `[` command. `[` is for performing string and numeric tests.

```
if ps aux | grep -v 'grep --color=auto' && ps aux | grep '/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -Dproc_balanicer'
then
```

You might want to use the `pgrep` command instead of `ps | grep`.